# How to prove: If $x \geq 0 $ and $x \leq \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $x = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, ordered-fields

I am trying to prove this problem for my homework. I am having some difficulty with this, because we are just supposed to use several ordered field axioms, the four order axioms, and several basic facts about the real numbers. If anyone can give me help or some guidance that would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: did you triad to use the trichotomy axiom?

Comment: Since $0\le x\le \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon$. Letting $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ implies that $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\epsilon = x/2$. What did you get ?

Comment: Can I suppose the $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$? That seems like a no-no considering that this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @anonymous - If the inequality does not hold for this choice of epsilon then I have found a positive number that disproves the claim that the inequality holds **for all** positive epsilon

Comment: I am struggling to find a contradiction with $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$. I can use the fact that: "for all x,y, and z $\in R$, if x < y and z > 0, then xz < yz"
I could say x is x and y is $\epsilon$ and z is also $\epsilon$, 
then $\frac{x^2}{2} < \frac{x^2}{4}$, which is a contradiction. Does that train of logic make sense?

Comment: @anonymous The contradiction I was thinking of is that setting $\epsilon=x/2$ gives us that $x\leq\frac{x}{2}$ so $x-\frac{x}{2}\leq\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$
thus $\frac{x}{2}\leq0$ and finally $x\leq0$. But $x\geq0$ so $x$
must be $0$

Comment: Ah ha! I see. Awesome. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x>0$. Now choose an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon\in(0,x)$